# How to properly prefix blog post URL's

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting

I want to prefix my blog posts with `/news/` and changing my Permalinks to `/news/%postname%` seems to do the trick.

However, I also have a few custom post types and for some reason those URL's are now also prefixed with `/news/`. Of course this is not what I want.

How can I make sure that only the out-of-the-box Wordpress post type is prefixed with `/news/`?

Comment: why don't you create a category called News to mark your posts, and set the links to /%category%/%postname% ????

Comment: Hmm. that seems to be a work around, albeit somewhat unclean. It's seems to be working though. Not sure yet how I feel about this solution in the long term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are not using a plugin to handle your post types but are registering them manually:

Add the `rewrite` argument to your [`register_post_type()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Parameters) function calls.

```
$rewrite = array(
    'slug' => $slug,
    'with_front' => false
);

$args = array(
    // your other arguments
    'rewrite' => $rewrite
);

register_post_type( 'name_of_your_post_type', $args );
```

If your registering your post types with some plugin, check whether it has an option to set `with_front` to `false`. It defaults to `true` (unfortunately, for your sake).

Whether there's a plugin out there that has this feature I don't know - never used no post type plugin(s).

Comment: 'with_front' => false was exactly what I was looking for.