# How do I prefix blog post urls as mysite.com/blog/%postname%/ but allow authors to still be located at mysite.com/authors/%nicename%?

Tags: custom-post-types, author, permalinks

I've tried a bunch of things but cannot find a solution that works.

I want my site to have the structure:

```
mysite.com/ = homepage
mysite.com/blogs/ = blog archive
mysite.com/blogs/year/ = blog archive (in a specific year)
mysite.com/blogs/year/month/ = blog archive (in a specific month)
mysite.com/blogs/year/month/postname = blog post
mysite.com/authors/ = authors archive
mysite.com/authors/nicename = author profile
mysite.com/customposttype/ = custom post type archive
mysite.com/customposttype/postname = custom post type post
```

Currently, with `/blogs/%year%/%month%/%postname%/` set as the permalink structure, everything works correctly except the authors part.  It forces it to `mysite.com/blogs/authors/` and `mysite.com/blogs/authors/nicename`, which is not desireable, since most authors will be making custom post types and not blogs.

Some posts I checked here but without the right answer:

[How to properly prefix blog post URL's](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/34252/how-to-properly-prefix-blog-post-urls)

[Permalinks Question: Adding a prefix ONLY in front of the posts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/52471/permalinks-question-adding-a-prefix-only-in-front-of-the-posts)

[Possible to change the URL for the regular post type without affecting the URL of other custom post types?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13411/possible-to-change-the-url-for-the-regular-post-type-without-affecting-the-url-o)

Comment: Also I realize that the structure of `/blogs/%postname%/` and `blogs/%year%/%month%/%postname%` are different in the title and content of the post, but those aren't the issue (I just typed it over a long period of time and didn't stay consistent).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the author base independently by manipulating the `$wp_rewrite` global:

```
function wpa55976_author_base() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->author_base = 'authors';
    $wp_rewrite->author_structure = '/' . $wp_rewrite->author_base . '/%author%';

    // EDIT - rewrite rule to force author urls to resolve:
    add_rewrite_rule('authors/([^/]+)/?$', 'index.php?author_name=$matches[1]', 'top');

}
add_action( 'init', 'wpa55976_author_base' );
```

Make sure to visit your permalinks page to flush rewrites after you add this.

The one thing you won't get is `mysite.com/authors/ = authors archive`, as WordPress doesn't provide this page by default, though you may be able to create an `authors` page and use a custom template, or add a rewrite rule to handle it.

Comment: Thanks!  This works to change the links to all point to `mysite.com/authors/name` but that link 404s every time, however, `mysite.com/blog/author/name` still displays the correct information.  Edit: and I just tried going to Settings -> Permalinks and saving to refresh the Permalinks.  No dice :-(

Comment: @ZachM - did you put it in the theme's `functions.php` file? the rewrite can't be present if the old author URLs still work. I've just tried it on a brand new 3.4 install with TwentyEleven theme and it's working here, if you could give that try and verify there's not otherwise a theme or plugin conflict.

Comment: I had it in my plugin.  I'll try switching it to functions.php.

Comment: I had the Edit Author Slug plugin activated from an earlier attempt, which was conflicting.  Once I turn it off, it works!  Thanks a million!

Comment: Actually it was working for a bit, then I went and added a custom taxonomy for something seemingly unrelated, and it broke again.  I have no other modifications of the global `$wp_rewrite` variable in either the theme or any active plugin.

Comment: With all plugins disabled, and your function added into functions.php, the home page displaying the first few posts have the correct link, `mysite.com/authors/authorname`, however when I click on them, I get a 404.  If I manually type `mysite.com/blogs/authors/authorname`, it shows the list of posts by that author.

Comment: I may just opt to create another custom post type called "blog" and do a quick SQL UPDATE to change the posts to blogs and do it that way.  I'll lose the `%year%/%month%/` part of the URL structure, but I may save myself a lot of headache figuring this out, since I can ditch the URL prefix entirely.

Comment: @ZachM - very strange, not sure what's happening. before you abandon it, you can try adding a rewrite rule with higher precedence, see edit above.